# How to get Id with Selenium Chromedriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get the Id of an iFrame directly with Selenium Chromedriver in Python without Javascript if possible, but I don't know why is failing.

When I do this I get wrong Id result as shown below.

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_class_name("MyClass").id
u'5b6a-c153-4e7f-90b2-b7e45'
```

If I send the following Javascript command on Chrome Console I get the correct frame Id:

```
> document.getElementsByClassName('MyClass')[0].id  
< "MyFrame89-0-bed65f30"
```

Now when I try to use the same Javascript command within `driver.execute_script()` it doesn't show anything.

```
>>> driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('MyClass')[0].id")
>>>
```

So, here I have 2 issues:

1- `driver.find_element_by_class_name().id` is not showing the correct `Id`

2- `driver.execute_script()` it doesn't show anything.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

A sample html code is here https://jsfiddle.net/k3x9rsa6/1/

Comment: What is the correct `id`? can you share the relevant HTML?

Comment: @DebanjanB Hello, thanks for answer. A sample code is here https://jsfiddle.net/k3x9rsa6/1/

Comment: `id` is an **HTML attribute** and not a class field. Try `.get_attribute("id")`.

Comment: @SiKing Excellent. Thanks so much for your help. Now it works. You can put it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id you're retrieving is NOT the html id attribute.
Try retrieving it one of these ways:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("MyClass").get_attribute("id")
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("MyClass").get_property("id")
```